# Can I disable blood on Splitgate?

Tags: splitgate-arena-warfare

Is there an option to disable the blood (including the blood spatter on the screen) in Splitgate Arena Warfare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can disable blood under the GAMEPLAY tab in the Settings menu.

[image]

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: does this remove the blood on the walls as well?